# Using a .lib file from C

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, static

I am new to C/C++. I have a static library (.lib) file created using VC++. (I also have .h file for it). And I need to use this in a C program. Can you please help me doing this?

Comment: Are youb compiling the C program with VC++?

Answer (score 3):

Can you clarify if you're trying to build an EXE or a DLL?

What you're looking for is known as static linking.  This will take the .lib file and essentially embed it into your application.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_linking

You'll need to change your project settings in VC++ to include this file to be one of the files linked into the process.  If you give us some more information about the Visual Studio version, we can provide a more specific answer about how to do this.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the question that DLLs are involved.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I am trying to use a static library (created using VC++) in a C program (exe).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using VC++ for your future C program, go to the project's Configuration Properties (in the Project menu, choose Properties).

Under C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories, add the folder where you have your .h file.

Under Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies, add the name of your .lib file.

Answer (score 0):

Note that such static libraries are typically for one compiler (and often even version) only.

Comment: I am using VC++ compiler for both.